# Angular 2 - Observable to Promise fails

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I'm struggling with converting an observable into a promise. I know that there's the `toPromise()` function on any `observable` but when I use this function it returns me `ZonedAwarePromise` with the properties:

`__zone_symbol_state: null` and `__zone_symbol_value: Array[0]`

Also, the `then` part of the promise never gets fired.

**Concrete Situation**

I want to send an http-api-request that reads a file and returns its content inside the Promise:

```
public getData(fileName: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.getHomeDirectory().then(homedir => {
            const fullFileName = homedir + fileName;
            const myApiRequest = "..." + fullFileName;
            return this.http.get(myApiRequest)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .toPromise()
                        .catch(this.handleError);
        });
    }
}
```

Calling this promise like so:

```
const fileName = '...';
this.fileService.getData(fileName).then( content => {
    console.log(content); // never gets fired!
});
```

I already tried different variations like replacing `return` with `resolve(...)` or `Promise.resolve(...)` and now I have no idea left how to fulfill this promise correctly in order to get the `then` part working.

Thank you in advance for any help and ideas!

Comment: Have you checked your network tab to see what you are actually receiving? `Array[0]` would suggest to me that there is something weird going on in your request/response handling :)

Answer (score 0):

in the `new Promise` callback you have to resolve :

```
 public getData(fileName: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.getHomeDirectory().then(homedir => {
            const fullFileName = homedir + fileName;
            const myApiRequest = "..." + fullFileName;
            this.http.get(myApiRequest)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError)
                        .subsucribe(data =>  {
                            resolve(data )
                        });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it seems like it will never be resolved. I don't know why but obviously the request delivers no response (not even an error) Any idea?